# Button Thread-Safe Calls to Windows Forms Controls C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, button, windows-forms-designer

I had read [this topic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms171728(v=vs.80).aspx) about how to Make Thread-Safe Calls to Windows Forms Controls .. But I don't really understand how to apply it to a button. In my case I have:

```
button.Enabled = false;
new Thread(() =>
{                   
    doSomeWork();
    button.Enabled = true;           
}).Start();
```

I want to enable the button when Thread ends.

Comment: I guess you didn't read the example completely. You need to call this.Invoke(...) in order to change the button.Enabled.

Comment: I don't know how to apply in my case because in the example they delegate a text.. I have no experience with threads on C#. Can you show me how to apply it in my case ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method in order to execute the code in UI thread:

```
button.Enabled = false;
new Thread(() =>
{                   
   doSomeWork();
   this.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {
         button.Enabled = true;
   });
}).Start();
```